# Why does creating a custom-sklearn Estimator score go down?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
class random(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self):
        self.model=xgboost.XGBClassifier()
    def fit(self,x,y):
        self.model.fit(x,y)
        return self.model
    def predict(self,x):
        return self.model.predict(x)
rfc=random()
val=cross_val_score(rfc,train_x_array[:,x.astype(bool)],train_y_array,scoring='accuracy',cv=10,n_jobs=-1)
val.mean()
```

> 0.7609086695594499

score downs??

```
val=cross_val_score(xgboost.XGBClassifier(),train_x_array[:,x.astype(bool)],train_y_array,scoring='accuracy',cv=10,n_jobs=-1)
val.mean()
```

> 0.8668378762815749

Is it the BaseEstimator's problem??

Comment: try setting `random_state` inside both `XGBClassifier`, for `cv` in `cross_val_score`. You will have to create something like `KFold` instance with `random_state` set and pass that as `cv` parameter instead of integer 10